# Command Line of SQLLocalDB in non-English Windows?

Tags: sql-server

MS SQLLocalDB has some simple commandline controls. For example, "SQLLocalDB info abc" returns some text with details of the server instance 'abc'. In English language windows, it looks like this:

```
Name: ABC
Version: 12.0.2000.8
Shared Name: 
Owner: Example\Name
Auto-create: No
State: Running
Last Start Time: 01/01/2001 00:00:00
Instance Pipe Name:
```

I need to parse this. My question is - does this text get translated on non-English Windows, or is it always in English? I don't have access to non-English windows to check.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else encounters this - here is the answer.

It depends on the language version of SQLLocalDB, not on the language of the Windows OS. If you install English language SQLLocalDB, commandline is in English.